# Displaying tabular data using only div element

Tags: css, header, tabular

I have a table and I need to add a global header like the image below .
[image]

I'm working only with divs, not table tags. I've tried many possibilities to make it work but it won't. Here is what the table looks like.

Here is what I've tried:

```css
.clsDashMap_sumSlideSiteContentSummary {
 position : absolute;
 top: 2rem;
 width: 100%;
 height: 14rem;
 color: #000000;
 text-align: center;
}
.clsDashMap_wrapTableSite {
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
 height: 14rem;
 border: 2px solid;
}
.tableSite_blocLogoCategorie {
 display: table-header-group;
 background-color: gray;
}
.siteLogoCategorie_cell {
 display: table-row;
 text-align: justify;
 padding: 10px;
 border: 2px solid red;
}
.tableSite_blocTitreCategorie {
 display: table-header-group;
 background-color: gray;
}
.siteTitleCategorie_cell {
 display: table-cell;
 text-align: justify;
 padding: 10px;
 border: 2px solid red;
}
.tableSite_blocFMTNT {
 display: table-row-group;
 background-color: gray;
 text-align: center;
}
.blocFMTNT-row {
 display: table-row;
 border: 2px solid;
}
.blocFMTNT-rowTitle {
 display: table-cell;
 text-align: justify;
 padding: 10px;
 border: 2px solid green;
}
.blocFMTNT-value {
 display: table-cell;
 text-align: justify;
 padding: 10px;
 border: 2px solid yellow;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: pink;
}
#pieChartAlm, #pieChartTkt {
 margin: auto;
 width: 5rem !important;
    height: 5rem !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideSiteContentSummary">
     <div class="clsDashMap_wrapTableSite">
          
                <div class="tableSite_blocLogoCategorie"> 
                    <div class="siteLogoCategorie_cell"> <div style="display: table-header-group;background-color: yellow;"> ALARMES</div></div>
                       <div class="siteTitleCategorie_cell" style="width:2rem;">Criticité</div>
                       <div class="siteTitleCategorie_cell" style="width:2rem;">Sans Sup</div>
                       <div class="siteTitleCategorie_cell" style="width:2rem;">Non Nominale</div>
                    </div>
                 

            <div style="display: table-header-group;background-color: yellow;"> TICKETS</div>
        <div class="tableSite_blocLogoCategorie"> 
                    <div class="siteLogoCategorie_cell">
                       <div class="siteTitleCategorie_cell">En cours</div>
                       <div class="siteTitleCategorie_cell">A suivre</div>
                       <div class="siteTitleCategorie_cell">Clôs</div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
       
            <div style="display: table-header-group;background-color: yellow;"> SITES</div>
        <div class="tableSite_blocLogoCategorie">
                  <div class="siteLogoCategorie_cell">
                        <div class="siteTitleCategorie_cell">Perte HF</div>
                        <div class="siteTitleCategorie_cell">-3DB</div>
                        <div class="siteTitleCategorie_cell">Décrochage HS</div>
                        <div class="siteTitleCategorie_cell">Alarme RX</div>
                        <div class="siteTitleCategorie_cell">GE</div>
                   </div>
                </div>

             <div class="tableSite_blocFMTNT">
               <div class="blocFMTNT-row">
                 <div class="blocFMTNT-rowTitle">TNT</div>
                 <div class="blocFMTNT-value"><canvas id="pieChartAlm" ></canvas></div>
                 <div class="blocFMTNT-value">1.2</div>
                 <div class="blocFMTNT-value">1.3</div>
                 <div class="blocFMTNT-value">1.4</div>
                 <div class="blocFMTNT-value">1.5</div>
                 <div class="blocFMTNT-value">1.6</div>
                 <div class="blocFMTNT-value">1.7</div>
                 <div class="blocFMTNT-value">1.8</div>
                 <div class="blocFMTNT-value">1.9</div>
                 <div class="blocFMTNT-value">1.10</div>
                 <div class="blocFMTNT-value">1.11</div>
               </div>
               <div class="blocFMTNT-row">
                 <div class="blocFMTNT-rowTitle">FM</div>
                 <div class="blocFMTNT-value"><canvas id="pieChartTkt" ></canvas></div>
                 <div class="blocFMTNT-value">2.2</div>
                 <div class="blocFMTNT-value">2.3</div>
                 <div class="blocFMTNT-value">2.4</div>
                 <div class="blocFMTNT-value">1.5</div>
                 <div class="blocFMTNT-value">1.6</div>
                 <div class="blocFMTNT-value">1.7</div>
                 <div class="blocFMTNT-value">1.8</div>
                 <div class="blocFMTNT-value">1.9</div>
                 <div class="blocFMTNT-value">1.10</div>
                 <div class="blocFMTNT-value">1.11</div>
               </div>
             </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Stick with tables, they are ideal for this sort of tabular data, then take a look at `colspan` attributes to span rows over applicable columns.
http://html.com/tables/rowspan-colspan/

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError  i have to work with divs instead of tables tag... i tried the colspan attributes , doesn't seem to work ..

Comment: You *have* to? Well, I suppose that can't be helped then. `colspan` is an attribute that needs to be applied to `table` elements, that's why it's not working on your `div` - did you check out the link I added? Sure you did. Anyway, keep exploring options, and good luck!

Comment: thank's, i'm searching ...it must be a way to do this or something equivalent to colspan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>As others mentioned in the comments, this *really* should be handled with a table element, but if you absolutely *must* use divs, it can be done (with trade-offs).</s>

The trick is to contain all cells or subheaders under a header within a container div for that header, and all of these cell or subheader elements need to display as inline-blocks.

To actually get it to look right, the highest level containing element must have its width set exactly to its contents unless you *want* it to extend the full width of the page. If you're not at all worried about responsive layout and/or how overflow in the cells behaves, you can figure it out (taking borders, margin, and padding into account, of course) and set it via CSS... otherwise you'll have to set it programmatically with JS and update it when needed.

Take a look at [this Codepen example I made](https://codepen.io/ABabin/pen/BZvbxy) or the code snippet of this working in action.

**UPDATE:**

I have found a much better, perhaps even ideal solution that gives you responsiveness. It uses the always wonderful but often forgotten: flex boxes! 
Go through the new snippet (or [Codepen](https://codepen.io/ABabin/pen/LLqrQb)) and read the comments I've put in to see how it's done. [This article](https://css-tricks.com/accessible-simple-responsive-tables/) is also a good resource for flex box tables.

```css
    /* Tables
================================== */
.table-container {
  width: 75%; // Sets table width relative to window width. 
  margin: 0 auto; // Centers table
}

.Rtable {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 0 3em 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.header-row {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

.header-row h3 {
  margin: 0;
}

.table-row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
.Rtable-cell { // This is applied to ALL table cells. 
  box-sizing: border-box; //This takes borders into account for sizing.
  padding: 0.8em 1.2em;
  // Depending on cell content, you may need to change 
  // overflow property, but in some cases, it might break 
  // the flexbox. 
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: solid 2px gray;
  background: lightgray;
}

//  These classes mimic the effect of the colspan attribute
//  IMPORTANT: The number of columns in your table will determine
//    the width percentages to use. 
//    For instance, for a table with 8 columns at the smallest level,
//    a colspan-1 would need to be set to 12.5%, colspan-2 to 25%, and so 
on.
.colspan-1 {
  width: 25%;
}
.colspan-2 {
  width: 50%;
}
.colspan-4 {
  width: 100%;
}

/* Page styling - None of this is particular important to the layout of the 
table.
================================== */
html { 
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #EEE; 
}
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 2em;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  background-color: white;
  border: double 3px #DDD;
  border-top: none; border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-container">
  <div class="Rtable">
    <!-- Breaking things up into rows is ultimately unnecessary 
         but if for any reason a cell were to go missing or an intentded 
row's cells' widths don't add up to 100%, without splitting into rows, the 
flexbox would fill in that gap with whatever cell is next... even if it's on 
the next row. -->
    <div class="table-row header-row">
      <div class="Rtable-cell colspan-4"><h3>I'm at the top level</h3></div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-row header-row">
      <div class="Rtable-cell colspan-2"><h3>I'm a second level header</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="Rtable-cell colspan-1"><h3>Also second level!</h3></div>
      <div class="Rtable-cell colspan-1"><h3>Me too!</h3></div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-row">
      <div class="Rtable-cell colspan-1">Regular cell row 1</div>
      <div class="Rtable-cell colspan-1">Regular cell row 1</div>
      <div class="Rtable-cell colspan-1">Regular cell row 1</div>
      <div class="Rtable-cell colspan-1">Regular cell row 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-row">
      <div class="Rtable-cell colspan-1">Regular cell row 2</div>
      <div class="Rtable-cell colspan-1">Regular cell row 2</div>
      <div class="Rtable-cell colspan-1">I'M JUST A PLAIN OL' CELL</div>
       <div class="Rtable-cell colspan-1">Regular cell row 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank's for the explanations...indeed i really want it to be responsive

Comment: Hey, I've found a much better solution. See my updated answer.

Comment: hey ABabin, thank you for the solution, it's a good one...but i have to code all the table structure again without table tags, only divs (nested) and float (not my decision) which is a bit complicated... so i wanted to know if display: flex is a a table tag or not ?....The purpose of that is to control each div in small devices..t-o be flexible

Comment: The flex properties are not standard table properties, no. I'm not even sure if it would work properly in a de facto HTML table. They're meant to flexibly specify how elements grow, shrink, or move to fill in space within the flex container. You wouldn't need to float anything. I'm pretty confident you could accomplish your goal with the HTML structure you included in your original question as is, but you'll have to figure that out for yourself, I'm afraid. [See here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for a guide to Flexbox.